# Protobuf error while trying to include c++ classes in python-tensorflow on aarch64 Architecture

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, protocol-buffers

Trying to import ctypes and use .so files with python tensorflow on aarch64 the following way:

```
import ctypes
import numpy as np
#import cv2


lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./serverfoo.so')


class image_data(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('to_dark', ctypes.c_int), 
                    ('to_bright', ctypes.c_int),
                    ('start_time_sec',ctypes.c_int),
                    ('start_time_nsec',ctypes.c_int),
                    ('capture_time_sec',ctypes.c_int),
                    ('capture_time_nsec',ctypes.c_int),
                    ('data', ctypes.ARRAY(ctypes.c_ubyte,960*1280*3))]
        def __repr__(self):
            return '({0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5})'.format(self.to_dark, 
                                                                    self.to_bright,
                                                                    self.start_time_sec,
                                                                    self.start_time_nsec,
                                    self.capture_time_sec,
                                        self.capture_time_nsec)


class image_server(object):
    def __init__(self):
        lib.image_server_new.argtypes = []
        lib.image_server_new.restype = ctypes.c_void_p

        lib.GetNewestImage.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p]
        lib.GetNewestImage.restype = image_data

        self.obj = lib.image_server_new()



    def GetNewestImage(self):
        return lib.GetNewestImage(self.obj)
```

leads to the following message (using the same code on an x86_64 works fine):

```
[libprotobuf FATAL google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc:61] This program requires version 3.6.1 of the Protocol Buffer runtime library, but the installed version is 2.6.1.  Please update your library.  If you compiled the program yourself, make sure that your headers are from the same version of Protocol Buffers as your link-time library.  (Version verification failed in "bazel-out/arm-opt/genfiles/external/com_github_googleapis_googleapis/google/bigtable/admin/v2/instance.pb.cc".)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'google::protobuf::FatalException'
  what():  This program requires version 3.6.1 of the Protocol Buffer runtime library, but the installed version is 2.6.1.  Please update your library.  If you compiled the program yourself, make sure that your headers are from the same version of Protocol Buffers as your link-time library.  (Version verification failed in "bazel-out/arm-opt/genfiles/external/com_github_googleapis_googleapis/google/bigtable/admin/v2/instance.pb.cc".)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Every suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you read the message from the exception? Have you tried doing what it suggests?

Comment: Hi thx for answering so fast. Yes I tried the following: changing version of protobuf  using pip installing a new protoc version - installing protobuf from sources and tensorflow from sources trying to change the version of the protobuf version tensorflow uses - deleting just the old protobuf version and replacing it with a link to a newer version - resulted in a real broken system - with freezing windows and other horrible experiences